# Unit testing functions from index.js

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I have added an add-function in the fulfillment section of Dialogflow which works perfectly fine, when called.

```
// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
// intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
// intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

function myadd(a,b){
    return a+b
}
```

I want to unittest that function with mocha. In order to do that I have to export the function for my test file, so I tried to do this in the following manner:

```
// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
// intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
// intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = {
    myaddfunction: (a, b) => {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

This change causes the error message: **function failed on loading user code. Error message: The function exported from file index.js as dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment needs to be of type function. Got: object**s

How will I be able to call my functions from index.js and export it for unittesting at the same time? I think I am missing a concept here.

I tried the below suggestion:

```
import isEmpty from './works';
```

In the works.js file in the same folder I have the following code:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


export {
    isEmpty
};
```

But then I get the error:

import isEmpty from './works';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Why do you export an object and not directly the function?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can write this. Yet, this may help.

```
function myadd(a,b){
  return a+b;
}
export {
  myadd
};
```

Now on your other file you can:

```
import myadd from "path to your module goes here";
```

Comment: I did it like you said, but I get the error: Unexpected identifier

Comment: did you get your path correct? The path should end with your file name. Like this from your code above: 
    
     import isEmpty from './works.js';